# Views taxonomy page by content type

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I've got two content types: "job" and "job description".

Both of these types are categorized by using ONE taxonomy vocabulary "category".

I've enabled the default "taxonomy term view" for views.

No when I navigate to the site /category/entertainment (for example) all jobs and job descriptions which are tagged with the category "Entertainment" will be displayed.
But I want to extend this view like:

- /category/entertainment/job => show all nodes of type "job" with the category Entertainment
- /category/entertainment/job_description => show all nodes of type "job_description" with the category Entertainment

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have to add a second parameter to your views page path so it looks somthing like this: `taxonomy/term/%/%`. The first % will be the category, the second will be the node type.

Now you have to add a contextual filter. Choose the filter "Content: Type". The default filter setting should work fine. You can try rewriting the title under "When value IN URL" to something like `node type %2` to see if the value is correct.

You can test it in the preview at the bottom by setting the parameters to "entertainment/job" or "entertainment/job_description".